# Remove(Delete) existing channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I built fabric network using kafka.
Then, I created 2 channels such as "channel_A" and "channel_B".

Now, I don't need "channel_B".
So, I want to remove(delete) this "channel_B" from my network.

Is there any way to remove(delete) it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no way to delete an existing channel from the Blockchain network. You can only append new data(normal transactions or configuration update) to the Blockchain network.